# AWS codepipeline doesn't have OpsWorks in the Deployment provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am following this document [AWS codepipeline creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/other-services-cp-chef12-pipeline.html) to create my codepipeline. Document suggests to select 'AWS Opsworks' as 'Deployment Provider', but I can't find it in the dropdown.

Is there anything that I should enable?

[Image URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6SjI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AWS CodePipeline support for AWS OpsWorks is currently available in the US East (N. Virginia) Region (us-east-1) only.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#integrations-deploy